# infer topic distributions on new, unseen documents with LDA and Gensim

Tags: python, lda

Suppose I have generated a latent Dirichlet allocation model of `Corpus1` using the basic command:

```
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus1, num_topics=25, id2word = dictionary, passes=50, minimum_probability=0)
```

My question would be, how can I classify the new documents from say `Corpus2'?

I am trying to use the following command `print(ldamodel[Corpus2[1]])` to obtain the distribution for the first document but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I am very confused regarding the class that the object `Corpus2` should be. Any suggestions of where to find more information or a tutorial is more than welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced a similar issue. Ensure that corpus2 has the same representation as corpus1.
By the looks of it, I'm guessing Corpus2[1] is a list of words appearing in a document. Vectorize the same. Perform a tf-idf transformation and then feed it to the model. That way, it has two elements. (word_id, tf-idf value)